# If $1<p<\infty, p^{-1}+q^{-1}=1,f\in L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^d),$ then there are $g\in L^{p}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and $h\in L^{q}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ such that $f=gh.$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

> If $1<p<\infty, p^{-1}+q^{-1}=1,$ and $f\in L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^d),$ show that there are $g\in L^{p}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and $h\in L^{q}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ such that $f=gh.$

$\textbf{My Thoughts:}$

I define $g,h$ as follows:
$$g(x)=\begin{cases}f(x)^{1/p}&\text{if }f(x)\geq0\\(-f(x))^{1/p}&\text{if }f(x)<0.\end{cases}$$
$$h(x)=\begin{cases}f(x)^{1/q}&\text{if }f(x)\geq0\\(-f(x))^{1/q}&\text{if }f(x)<0.\end{cases}.$$
Since $f\in L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^d),$ we have that
$$\|g\|_{p}=\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\vert f\vert\right)^{1/p}<\infty,$$
and similarly for $h$. Therefore, $g\in L^{p}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and $h\in L^{q}(\mathbb{R}^d).$

Finally, if $f(x)\geq 0,$ then $g(x)\cdot h(x)=f(x)^{1/p}\cdot f(x)^{1/q}=f(x)$ since $p^{-1}+q^{-1}=1.$ Similarly, if $f(x)<0$ then $g(x)\cdot h(x)=(-f(x))^{1/p}\cdot (-f(x))^{1/q}=f(x).$

---

Do you agree with the above proof? Any feedback is much appreciated.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: No, your construction only gives $gh=|f|$, because $g=|f|^{1/p}$ and $h=|f|^{1/q}$. To make amends, simply multiply sign of $f$ to either of $g$ and $h$.